# Why I'm not redirected properly to base_url() in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

While clicking on this button, I'm not being redirected to base_url(), but to 'current_url'/base_url().

Line in config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/projekt/';
```

Code in header:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">Nav</a>
```

I'm being redirected to site 'localhost/projekt/localhost/projekt/', instead of 'localhost/projekt/'.

I can't find any solution on the web. Is there a way to do this properly?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `href` does not start with `http://` or `/` so the browser will simply append the url into your current url.

Take a look at the difference here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ChinLeung/c1t6vw4v/

To fix it, change your config to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projekt/';
```

Answer (score 1):

change line in config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/projekt/';
```

it will be

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projekt/';
```